# Supposedly identical code results in different routing behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing a web application and in my Angular front-end code i defined the following `isLoggedIn()` function to check if the user is authenticated:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    // irrelevant code is omitted for brevity

    private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(AuthService.KEY_USER))
    );

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value &&
            (this.currentUserSubject.value.expiresAtMillis > Date.now());
    }
}
```

In my routing module i have the following route definition:

```
{ path: ':id', component: DetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, IdGuard] }
```

`AuthGuard` checks if the user is logged in:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And `IdGuard` checks if the `id` parameter is a number:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (isNaN(Number(route.paramMap.get('id')))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This all works fine, the route is accessible only when the user is authenticated and the `id` param is a number.

The problem occurs when i change the `AuthGuard` code to be more idiomatic:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    // old code
    // if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
    //     return true;
    // }
    // return false;

    // new code
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

With this new code the route is accessible even if the user is **not** authenticated.

If i remove the `IdGuard` from the route (so only the `AuthGuard` is applied), then it works fine, <strike>so i guess it has to do something with how these two guards interact with each other,</strike> but i cannot figure out the exact problem.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this behavior to me.

**EDIT**:

I think i've found the problem. If `currentUserSubject.value` is `null`, then the following expression returns `null` instead of `true` or `false`:

```
return this.currentUserSubject.value &&
    (this.currentUserSubject.value.expiresAtMillis > Date.now());
```

So the following is working as expected:

```
// checking explicitly for null
return this.currentUserSubject.value == null &&
    (this.currentUserSubject.value.expiresAtMillis > Date.now());
```

And this one as well:

```
// converting to Boolean
return Boolean(this.currentUserSubject.value) &&
    (this.currentUserSubject.value.expiresAtMillis > Date.now());
```

But why is this happening?

Shouldn't `this.currentUserSubject.value` be automatically converted to a `Boolean` value when used in an expression like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your edit:

The logical operators `&&` and `||` do not always return boolean values:

- `A && B` returns the value *A* if *A* is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy); otherwise, it returns *B*.
- `A || B` returns the value *A* if *A* is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy); otherwise, it returns *B*.

Some examples:

- `null && true` is `null`
- `"hello" || false` is `"hello"`
- `1 && 2` is `2`
- `0 || undefined` is `undefined`

More examples can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).